# Difference between DATEDIF unit "d" and "yd"

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to understand how the difference between DATEDIF(date1,date2,"d") and DATEDIF(date1,date2,"yd") in excel. It is very confusing when trying to deal with leap year dates.

for example

`=DATEDIF("2/29/2020","3/1/2021","yd")` gives `0`.

but when I try to give

`=DATEDIF("2/29/2020","3/1/2021","d")` gives `1`.

and one more thing is

`=DATEDIF("2/1/2020","3/1/2021","yd")` gives 29 and

`=DATEDIF("2/1/2019","3/1/2021","yd")` gives 28.

Some of the articles claim that year of start date is used for calculations so with that logic `DATEDIF("2/29/2020","3/1/2021","yd")` should give `1` instead of zero. Can someone explain how the calculations are being done and what year is being considered for the calculations?

Comment: `DATEDIF` is part of Excel primarily to provide support to old Lotus 1-2-3 workbooks, and will give inaccurate results under certain circumstances, as you have found. Not much to be done about that, except devise workarounds that will satisfy your desired algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/datedif-function-25dba1a4-2812-480b-84dd-8b32a451b35c) you can see what is the difference.

To be explicit, the `YD` variant isn't taking year into account, thus showing different results in the case of leap year.

Comment: can you elaborate "YD variant isn't taking year into account, thus showing different results in the case of leap year" more please ?

Comment: and why does DATEDIF("2/29/2020","3/1/2021","yd") give 0 while it should be 1 ?

Comment: Well that could be design feature, what happens in this calculation is that it is looking at date index relative to `01/01` and subtracting the results. It doesn't know about leap years, nor does it look for relationship between given dates.

Comment: With all that said, your `3/1/2021` is parsed as `3/1` and it is using the non-leap year index. `2/29/2020` on the other hand is a valid date and it is indexing it the same way, returning the same index as for the `3/1` variant.

Comment: What also seems to be true is that year indexing seems to be favoring 1st parameter, but that is really up to the algorithm they used, and you'll hardly reach that.

Comment: and interestingly DATEDIF("3/1/2019", "2/29/2020", "yD") gives 365 for which I cant think of any explanation given that DATEDIF("2/29/2020","3/1/2021","yd") gives 1

Comment: That is just ridiculous solution for some edge case. You can report it to them :D